# Adding a message box to an if tree got me an unreachable code warning

Tags: c#, messagebox

I have this method (below) which tests several conditions for various invalid data forms.

In the event that the method finds invalid data, it returns false. The logic works. The problem is that I want to notify the user specifically the issue.

I tried adding a message before the return statement, but visual studio warns me that code is unreachable after that point.  Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong?

My method (and attempted message box has been commented out)

```
private Boolean isValidData()
    {
        if (!isPresent(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
            //MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value for this field,"Data Error");
            return false;
        if (!isPresent(txt_DepartDate, "Departure Date"))
            return false;
        if (!isValidDate(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
            return false;
        if (!isValidDate(txt_DepartDate, "Departure Date"))
            return false;
        if (!isOnOrAfterToday(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
            return false;
        if (!isOnOrAfterToday(txt_DepartDate, "Departure Date"))
            return false;
        if (!isAfterArrivalDate(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date", txt_DepartDate, "Departure Date"))
            return false;

        return true;


    }
```

As a note, the validation methods pass the name because I would prefer to show the messagebox from within the method, rather than in this method.

For Example:

```
        private Boolean isPresent(TextBox textbox, string name)
    {
        if (textbox.Text == "" || textbox.Text == null)
            MessageBox.Show("Data must be entered for" + name, "Data Error");
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Yet, on the return true statement, I get the code unreachable warning.

Comment: I don't know if this recent answer of mine could help you. [Find here the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663662/c-sharp-displaying-error-messages-by-completing-a-simple-registration-form/26663966#26663966)

Comment: The commented part would work if you wrote your `if` statement with brackets: `if (...) { MessageBox.Show(...); return false; }`

Comment: Shows unreachable because an if without bracket only covers the following line. It have nothing to do with which line is indented, it's only for the next line. Use brackets if you have multiple lines.

Comment: @Mephy Yep this is why VS throws an error, the "Return false" gets executed 100% of the time, anything after it is unreachable.

Comment: Wow. This is what happens without coffee. Thanks guys, long night for me, not sure how I overlooked that

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: Lines have absolutely nothing to do with it either.  Only statements

Comment: @BenVoigt Indeed. But people writing multiple statements per line are _extremely_ rare. It is not the case for the OP, and it's easier to explain it that way, just in case 'statement' could be confusing.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: They might start, if they believed your comment to be correct.

Comment: Bad design. You check a value and if it fails you show your message. The user fixes it and you trigger another one. I can feel the frustration from here.

Comment: by the way I think you're missing a quote here: //MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value for this field,"Data Error");

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, well no.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with two *very* different bits of code, depending on whether that is a comment.

In this one

```
if (!isPresent(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
        //MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value for this field,"Data Error");
        return false;
```

the `return false;` is conditioned on the `if` matching.

In this one

```
if (!isPresent(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value for (this field)","Data Error");
        return false;
```

The message box is conditioned, and the return always happens.  That makes everything below it unreachable, as the compiler told you.

This isn't python, indentation has no effect on the behavior.

You're probably looking for

```
if (!isPresent(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
{
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value for (this field)","Data Error");
        return false;
}
```

Now *both* the message box and the `return false;` are controlled by the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

It's unreachable because you forgot to surround both lines in curly braces. Currently you've got this:

```
if (!isPresent(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value for this field,"Data Error");

return false;
```

The `return false` statement runs regardless of whether or not the first `if` statement returns `true` or `false`, so nothing after that point will ever run.

You want this:

```
if (!isPresent(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value for this field,"Data Error");
    return false;
}
```

Better yet, you might consider building up your error message, so they don't find out about one problem, then next time find out about another problem, and so on.

Something like this:

```
private bool IsValidData()
{
    var errorMessages = new List<string>();

    if (!isPresent(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
        errorMessages.Add("You must enter a value for this field.");
    if (!isPresent(txt_DepartDate, "Departure Date"))
        errorMessages.Add("Another message.");
    if (!isValidDate(txt_ArrivalDate, "Arrival Date"))
        errorMessages.Add("Another message.");

    ...

    if (errorMessages.Any())
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorMessages), "Errors");

    return !errorMessages.Any();  // returns false if errors found, otherwise true
}
```